# Decompressing or Extracting the XZ Frida Server?

Tags: android, emulation, frida, xz

I am trying to push Frida onto an Android Emulator.  To do this you use Android Device Bridge (adb) to "push" the frida server to a folder.  I downloaded the server.  It comes in a xz file format.

When I open the xz file with the Frida Android server in it in 8 Zip Pro it will extract it to a file folder.   The instructions for pushing frida server seem to indicate there is just one file that goes over.  Not a file folder.

I have seem other refer to "decompressing" the xz file first.  What tools can be used to "decompress" this file.   If I need to do something else to this file please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Use [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/). It is available for every platform and can handle all common and a lot of rare compression formats - xz included. BTW: That you get a directory (with one file in it) is a problem of the used decompression tool. The xz file itself does only contain one single file without any directory.

Comment: Solved!    Thank you Robert.  I was able to just open and decompress the file via 7 Zip where that option was not available in 8 Zip Pro (that I could find)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the command line to unzip it:

**#unzip it**
unxz frida-server-15.1.14-android-x86.xz

And then the following steps would be:

**#change the name**
mv frida-server-15.1.14-android-x86.xz frida-server

**#push to device**
adb push frida-server /data/local/tmp

**#change permissions**
adb shell "chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/frida-server"

**#Run frida-server**
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/frida-server